# NSIS: How do I delete a Label or any other control that is available in nsDialogs?

Tags: nsis

Scenario:
I have a checkBox, created using ${NSD_CreateCheckBox}. Using the approach given at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#step-notify, for ${NSD_OnClick}, I create a Label using ${NSD_CreateLabel}, below the checkBox whenever it gets check marked.

Now, how do I delete the Label I created below the CheckBox, when I uncheck the checkBox control.

Is there something like ${NSD_Delete*} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no delete macro but you can implement your own if you really need it but usually you just show/hide a control instead.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!ifndef NSD_DestroyControl
!define NSD_DestroyControl "!insertmacro NSD_DestroyControl "
!macro NSD_DestroyControl h
System::Call 'USER32::DestroyWindow(i${h})'
#Could also use: SendMessage ${h} ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0
!macroend
!endif

Page Custom MyPage
Page InstFiles

Var CheckShowHide
Var Lbl1
Var CheckDestroy
Var Lbl2

Function MyPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 30u 100% 10u "Show/Hide"
Pop $CheckShowHide
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 50u 100% 12u "Hello"
Pop $Lbl1
${NSD_OnClick} $CheckShowHide ShowHide
${NSD_Check} $CheckShowHide

${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 70u 100% 10u "Create/Destroy"
Pop $CheckDestroy
${NSD_OnClick} $CheckDestroy CreateDestroy

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function ShowHide
Pop $0
${NSD_GetState} $CheckShowHide $0
${If} $0 = ${BST_UNCHECKED}
  ShowWindow $Lbl1 0
${Else}
  ShowWindow $Lbl1 1
${EndIF}
FunctionEnd

Function CreateDestroy
Pop $0
${NSD_GetState} $CheckDestroy $0
${If} $0 = ${BST_UNCHECKED}
  ${NSD_DestroyControl} $Lbl2
${Else}
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 90u 100% 12u "World"
  Pop $Lbl2
${EndIF}
FunctionEnd
```